# How to append a RANDOM string to all occurrences of another string in file

Tags: regex, string, perl, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that would modify all occurrences of a certain string in a file.

I have a file with a bunch of text, in which urls occur. All urls are in the following format:`http://goo.gl/abc23` (that's goo.gl/, followed by 4 OR 5 alphanumeric characters).

What I'd like do is append a string to all urls. I managed (with the help of user [Dan Fego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34426/dan-fego)) to get this done with sed, but it only works by appending a static string.

What I'm looking for is a way to append a **different string to each occurrence**. Let's say I have a function `generatestring` that echoes a different string every time. I'd like to append a different generated string to each url. `http://goo.gl/abc23` would become `http://goo.gl/abc23?GeneratedString1`, `http://goo.gl/JB007` would become `http://goo.gl/JB007?GeneratedString2` and so on.

Does anyone know if this can be done? I've been told that perl is the way to go, but I have zero experience with perl. That's why I'm asking here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are the strings generated? Are they function of the matched url? or something else?

Comment: No, they are just random 5 character alphanumeric strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the  URLs aren't alone in each line, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub generate {
    my $i = shift;
    return "GeneratedString$i";
}
my $i = 0;
while(my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s~(http://\S+)~$1 . "?" . &generate($i++)~eg;
    print $line;
}
```

**usage:**

```
test.pl file_to__modify
```

**output:**

```
http://goo.gl/abc23?GeneratedString1
http://goo.gl/JB007?GeneratedString2
```

Comment: This one is actually pretty close to what I need. Can it be modified to take advantage of the fact that all urls are in the same format `http://goo.gl/*****` (5 alphanumeric characters at the end). Because some of the links are not space delimited.

Comment: OK, managed to do it. I replaced `(http://\S+)` with `(http://goo.gl/\w{5})`. Is that the correct way to go? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

ETA: Assuming the URLs are embedded in other text:

```
$ perl -lnwe 's#http://goo.gl/\w{5}\K\b# "?" . rand(100) #ge; print' googl.txt
```

For example:

```
$ cat googl 
random text here, and perhaps some html <a href="http://goo.gl/abc23">
more stuff http://goo.gl/abc23 foo fake link http://foo.bar/abc12
longer http://goo.gl/abc23123123 foo fake link http://foo.bar/abc12
$ perl -lnwe 's#http://goo.gl/\w{5}\K\b# "?" . rand(100) #ge; print' googl
random text here, and perhaps some html <a href="http://goo.gl/abc23?69.998515">
more stuff http://goo.gl/abc23?26.186867532985 foo fake link http://foo.bar/abc12
longer http://goo.gl/abc23123123 foo fake link http://foo.bar/abc12
```

`-l` [`chomps`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the file and adds newline to `print.` `-n` adds a `while(<>)` loop around the script, which basically means it reads either from argument file names or from STDIN. `\K` means "keep the matching text", `\b` is word boundary, so that you do not match partial strings.

Do note that it will still match `http://goo.gl/abc12/foo`, but since I do not know what your data looks like, you will have to determine what boundaries are acceptable.

Of course, `rand(100)` is just there as a placeholder for whatever function you intend to use.

If you needed the script version, here's the deparsed code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s[http://goo.gl/\w{5}\K\b]['?' . rand(100);]eg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: wow, @TLP the first line really looks to me like some random characters put together. :) I'm not used to it yet. :) How can I use m0skit0's generate_string function to generate random suffix with your one-liner?

Comment: @zigamilek If you want to add a subroutine of that length, I'd advise you to instead make it a script, using the code at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a lot of languages, but in Perl it's pretty straight forward:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use constant MAX_RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH => 5;

my $regex_url = '(http://goo.gl/\w{5})';

my @alphanumeric = ("A".."Z", "0".."9");
my $random_cap = $#alphanumeric + 1;

sub generate_string
{
    my $string = "?";
    for (my $i = 0; $i < MAX_RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH; $i++)
    {
        $string .= $alphanumeric[int(rand($random_cap))];
    }
    return $string;
}

my @input = <>;

for(@input)
{   
    my $cur = $_;
    while ($cur =~ /$regex_url/)
    {
        $cur = $';
        my $new_url = $1 . generate_string();       
        s/$1/$new_url/g;
    }
}

print(@input);
```

Usage:

```
script_name.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: No problem, it's pretty easy using Perl anyway. Here you go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't do what I need. I think I wasn't clear enough before. The links appear IN TEXT. For example: blah blah blah, http://goo.gl/abc23, random random, http://goo.gl/JB007.

They DO NOT appear one per line, and the file DOES NOT contain only links.

Comment: Then what's the format of the URLs? Any URL-compilant string? How do I know when the URL ends? Are they delimited by something?

Comment: `s/$/generate_string()/e, print for <>` is a bit more compact. You'll also want to forget everything you know about `chop`, and start using `chomp` instead.

Comment: TY about chop. But I don't like to compact things, Perl is already cryptic enough to make it even more cryptic...

Comment: Wow thanks guys for all your help. URLs are all in the same format: `http://goo.gl/*****` (5 alphanumeric characters).

Comment: Actually, it's not cryptic at all, it's rather mundane. Everything can be read as sequences of commands/variables that are interpolated into strings or lists. For example, from right to left: `for <>` a postscript for loop with all elements of <>, passed to the statement `s///, print`, which will execute the substitution first, then the print. Everything uses `$_`.

Comment: BTW @m0skit0, thanks for the function to generate a random string. It's much nicer than mine. :)

Comment: You're welcome. @TLP: I didn't say it's unreadable or I didn't understand it. I like to be able to understand the code with less effort possible. Perl is cryptic per se, and that's cryptic. It's too cryptic for me.

Comment: Edited the answer as requested by OP

Comment: @m0skit0 Please refrain from stating your subjective opinion as an objective fact. Perl is *not* cryptic "per se". I find that perl is very mundane, and reads pretty much like English. Try it for yourself: "substitute and print for this list". `s///, print for <>`. Same thing.

Comment: Perl is not cryptic "per se"? A language that uses implicit variables and almost everything is written in symbols, not to talk about regexes, subroutines with no parameters... is not "cryptic"? Anyway, I'll tell you a joke: "One day Larry Wall hit his head against the keyboard. Perl was born". And sorry, but I couldn't help but ROFL at "reads pretty much as English"

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm sorry, but just because you say something does not make it true. Perl does not use "implicit variables", it uses one implicit variable: `$_`, and it is clearly documented *where* it can be used. Regexes are not perl's invention. Perl subroutines do  have parameters, and I have no idea what you mean by "written in symbols". I find that perl reads just like English, and I just gave you an example. IMO, your point of view is dogmatic: "I refuse to learn things that look complicated, because they look complicated."

Comment: @m0skit0 If you wish to continue to believe that perl is difficult and cryptic, you are free to do so. All I ask is that you state that as your opinion, not as a fact.

Comment: You don't know me and you're putting words in my mouth I never said, like "I refuse to learn". Anyway, **IMHO** Perl is cryptic, Perl does use "implicit variables" ($_, @_, and others) which difficult legibility, but I love it, otherwise I won't be answering such questions. I'm off, have fun with Perl :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
gs(){  echo $(tr -cd '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c5); }
export -f gs
cat <<\! file
> http://goo.gl/abc23
> http://goo.gl/JB007
> bunch of text http://goo.gl/qwert another bunch of text
> another bot http://goo.gl/qwert another bot http://goo.gl/qaza
!
sed '\|http://goo\.gl/[0-9a-zA-Z]\{4,5\}\>|{s//&?'\''$(gs)'\''/g;s/^/echo '\''/;s/$/'\''/}' file |
sh
http://goo.gl/abc23?0Az23
http://goo.gl/JB007?ugczB
bunch of text http://goo.gl/qwert?LDW27 another bunch of text
another bot http://goo.gl/qwert?U9my2 another bot http://goo.gl/qaza?Ybtlp
```